# How to implement typescript code into vue component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nativescript-vue

https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-texttospeech

texttospeech has documentation written in TS.

**How to translate code into ns-VUE?**

```js
import { TNSTextToSpeech, SpeakOptions } from 'nativescript-texttospeech';

let TTS = new TNSTextToSpeech();

let speakOptions: SpeakOptions = {
  text: 'hello world',
};

TTS.speak(speakOptions);
```

I don't want to use typescript, all I need is a button that talks in Nativescript-Vue .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Typescript is just a superscript to javascript. If you have native javascript code it will work just the same. Are you getting any errors when building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is trying to convert TS to vanilla JS please try [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

This was what I was trying to do.

```js
<template>
  <Page>
    <ActionBar title="Welcome" />
    <StackLayout>
      <Label class="message" :text="speakOptions.text" col="0" row="0" />
      <Button text="talk" @tap="talk('welcome')" />
    </StackLayout>
  </Page>
</template>

<script >
import { TNSTextToSpeech } from "nativescript-texttospeech";

let TTS = new TNSTextToSpeech();

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      speakOptions: {
        text: "hello"
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    talk: function(message) {
      this.speakOptions.text = message;
      TTS.speak(this.speakOptions);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the type from the `speakOptions` and remove it from the import:

```
import { TNSTextToSpeech } from 'nativescript-texttospeech';

let TTS = new TNSTextToSpeech();

let speakOptions = {
  text: 'hello world',
};

TTS.speak(speakOptions);
```